# Почему удаляется моё сообщение, а не бот? Python pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot

Мое сообщение удаляется, а нужно бота. Что делать?

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выполняем...', reply_markup=a)
time.sleep(5)
bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Оплатите товар', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Видимо потому что переменная `message` содержит информацию именно о вашем сообщении

Answer (score 1):

Делай так

```py
msg_to_delete = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выполняем...', reply_markup=a)
time.sleep(5)
bot.delete_message(msf_to_delete.chat.id, msg_to_delete.id)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Оплатите товар', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Можете помочь с этим вопросом, если не сложно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1441008/Почему-не-изменяется-сообщение-бота-телеграм